# How to start non-systemd service on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: services, systemd

I installed `fwknop-server` package on the newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to start its daemon. The package does not provide `systemd` unit file and instead uses old init scripts which report as `active(exited)`:

```
$ service fwknop-server status
● fwknop-server.service - LSB: start and stop fwknopd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/fwknop-server; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2016-10-01 18:24:16 CEST; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 32581 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/fwknop-server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 32618 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/fwknop-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 01 18:24:16 fwknop systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop fwknopd...
Oct 01 18:24:16 fwknop systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop fwknopd.

$ ps aux | grep fwknop
jakuje   32727  0.0  0.0  14224   928 pts/0    S+   19:11   0:00 grep --color=auto fwknop
```

Starting or stopping does not change the status nor does start the `fwknopd`. This is more general question about the "legacy" init.d service, but I accept reasonable answers fitting for the `fwknop` itself, except starting the `fwknop` manually.

**Edit:**
The virtual machine have different network interface than the default expected by `fwknop`. This can be fixed by modifying `/etc/fwknop/fwknop.config` with

```
PCAP_INTF                   ens3;
```

but still the service is not starting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Change `START_DAEMON="yes"` in the file `/etc/default/fwknop-server`.

## Explanation

> The package does not provide systemd unit file […]

Debian and Ubuntu do not.  The software's authors, however, do:

- [`fwknopd.service`](https://github.com/mrash/fwknop/blob/master/extras/systemd/fwknopd.service)

This can be improved:

```
[Unit]
Documentation=http://askubuntu.com/a/832231/43344
Description=Firewall Knock Operator Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=fwknop
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0700
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fwknopd --foreground
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[Lennart Poettering wrote in 2011](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/on-etc-sysinit.html):

> Many of the configuration settings in `/etc/sysconfig` allow disabling services. By this they basically become a second level of enabling/disabling over what the init system already offers: when a service is enabled with `systemctl enable` or `chkconfig on` these settings override this, and turn the daemon of[f] even though the init system was configured to start it. This of course is very confusing to the user/administrator, and brings virtually no benefit.

And that is precsisely what the van Smoorenbug `rc` script in your package is doing:

```
START_DAEMON="no"
DAEMON_ARGS=""
[ -r /etc/default/fwknop-server ] && . /etc/default/fwknop-server

# Exit if the dameon must not be started
[ "$START_DAEMON" = "yes" ] || exit 0
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the links and explanation to my missing knowledge (I do package `fwknop` in Fedora and we use the upstream systemd unit file which works just fine. Therefore I was confused by the Ubuntu behavior). Can you explain why the `RuntimeDirectory` should come here?